# How to access GIT_COMMIT env variable in bash file

Tags: bash, jenkins

I am creating bash file in which i want to access only one environment variable of Jenkins i.e GIT_COMMIT.

Answer (score 1):

$GIT_COMMIT should be available from your "Execute shell" build step.